# Need Address Book to Appear in ALL Dual Boot Operating Systems

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, thunderbird, dualboot, address-book

My main computer has 3 O/S's (WinXP, Win7, and Win10) on separate partitions.  I initially (YEEAARS ago) set up Thunderbird in XP. Added a Win7 partition (maybe 2010 or so) using the T-Bird e-mail data from the XP partition, correctly editing the profiles.ini file, and EVERYTHING in the Win7 T-Bird (all mail folders and address book info) showed up fine.

Recently (maybe 2016) added a Win10 partition, but didn't use it much.  Now I'm preparing to (FINALLY) use Win10 as my primary O/S and I installed T-Bird (in 2022) on Win10 and checked that all mail was showing up fine, just as it appeared in Win7 - but I did NOT check the address book.  I made the appropriate edits to the Profiles.ini file and redirected everything to the correct location in my WinXP partition.  I didn't discover that the address book entries weren't showing up in Win10 until last week.

So now - Win7's mail & address book shows up fine, but in Win10 only the mail shows up, but no address book data.  All of the Abook.mab files seem to be ok as they always were.  What could be the reason for no address book ONLY in Win10??

Comment: Export the address book in Win 7 and see if you can successfully import into Win 10 Thunderbird.  Win 10 Thunderbird is very likely different format than for XP or Win 7.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out!!  Had no idea how OLD the T-bird version was on my Win10 system.  Just updated it to 102.12.0 and all is well with the address book!  I apologize for not checking this before posting.  Take care!  :-)